# Can't access WordPress wp-login.php from within Facebook app

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I deleted WordPress and started afresh and even created another new app on Facebook but still the issue remains.

I have set up a Facebook app which points to my WordPress site.
All parts of the site work, except I cannot click the register or login buttons.
If I log in from outside Facebook and refresh the Facebook app/page then I appear logged in and can do what I want, including log out.

Any ideas please? Unfortunately, most Google searches think I am talking about third party Facebook connect plugins, which I'm not.

The page in question is [here](http://apps.facebook.com/costaclassifiedsns/), which is just looking at [www.costablancaclassifieds.com](http://www.costablancaclassifieds.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell Brad, this seems to be less of a FB problem and more of a WP cookie issue.  I tried framing your site in with an iframe and it reacted similarly to the problem you're experiencing.  Looked around a bit and found others with similar problems; issue being that when you're serving a WP site to another domain via an iframe the cookies aren't able to be set properly.

Here's one forum topic I found:  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/running-wordpress-in-an-iframe-cross-domains

It's not good news, but hopefully it helps you find a solution or at least get some level of closure.  I'll try to think of a creative solution for your situation.

Comment: Thank you VERY much Mike. I didnt know it was because of iFrames. because of what you wrote I was able to change what i was googling for and then found, albeit perhaps not so desirable, a solution that now works. (perhaps you could test on your end too?)

I modified a few lines in the wordpress codebase.

1) open wp-includes/default-filters.php
2) find "frame"
3) you'll get two lines:

add_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );

4) comment those lines out,save and clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without modifying any of the core code. Just put these 2 lines in your functions.php

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header',     10, 0 ); // main site
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 ); // admin
```

Comment: Can these be added to a plugin too? If yes, any particular position? I've added them at the beginning of the plugin and the header is still set.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you *very* much, Mike. I didn't know it was because of iFrames. Because of what you wrote I was able to change what I was searching for and then found, albeit perhaps not so desirable, a solution that now works. (Perhaps you could test on your end too?) I modified a few lines in the Wordpress code base:

1. open `wp-includes/default-filters.php`
2. find `"frame"`
3. you'll get two lines:

   ```
   add_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
   add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
   ```
4. comment those lines out, save and clear cache.